# Number formatter not allowing decimals to show

Tags: ios, swift, numberformatter

Here is the obligatory "I'm new to programming" but, I've searched all available answers and have concluded that my issue **may** be more logic related than code, but I could be wrong about that too. I'm building a calculator app and everything is working except the `numberFormatter` (to show comma separators) in the display.  Whenever I try to format the number in the display, I can't get the display to show the decimal and the commas.

If I start with a decimal .1234 , I get 0.1234 and if I type 12345 I get 12,345 but if i type 12345.678, I get 12,345.  I'm losing the decimals.  I've tested it and my function to remove extraneous "." doesn't seem to be the issue.  And If I run the string extension `numberFormatter` outside of the label formatting controls it seems to work, but I need to guard against multiple decimals and extraneous "0"s.

I'm showing the code to the IBAction covering the buttons showing up on the display label, `display.text` which is the issue.  All calculations after this are working fine, with the `replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")` to create a clean string to convert to Double and calculate.

I'm using a sting extension to do the formatting.  I've been working on and off on this for weeks.  Any ideas? Do I have to refactor how I enter text into the `label.text`?

here is the code to add text to the `UILabel display`.

```
@IBAction func btnTouchDigit(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let digit = sender.currentTitle!

        if isUserTyping {
            var formattedNumber = ""

            print( "is user typting + String\(isUserTyping)")

            // make sure we aren't adding a second period

            var textCurrentlyInDisplay = display.text
            textCurrentlyInDisplay = textCurrentlyInDisplay?.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")

            if digit == "." && ((textCurrentlyInDisplay?.range(of: ".")) != nil) {
                return
            }
            else {
                formattedNumber = (textCurrentlyInDisplay! + digit)
                print("formattedNumber = \(formattedNumber.twoFractionDigits)")
                display.text = formattedNumber.twoFractionDigits

                // put code here to format label.text to show thousand seperators
                print("textCurrentlyInDisplay end = \(textCurrentlyInDisplay!)")     
            }
        }

          // make sure we aren't entering a bunch of zero's        
        else { print("else + \(isUserTyping)")

            display.text = digit
            if digit == "0" {return}
            else if digit == "." {display.text = "0."}
            // display.text = (digit == "." ? "0" : "") + digit
            isUserTyping = true
        }

    }
```

Here is my extension to handle the string conversion for the `numberFormatter`.

```
extension String {
    var twoFractionDigits: String {
        let styler = NumberFormatter()
        styler.minimumFractionDigits = 0
       styler.maximumFractionDigits = 16
       styler.numberStyle = .decimal
        let converter = NumberFormatter()
        converter.decimalSeparator = "."
        if let result = converter.number(from: self) {
            return styler.string(from: result)!
        }
        return ""

    }
```

Comment: There's no problem with your `twoFractionDigits` method. Call that on `"1234.56"` results in `1,234.56` as expected. So your issue is elsewhere. Use your debugger and see what happens when you have entered `1234.` and you then tap the `5`.

Comment: I put a breakpoint at the end of the btnTouchDigit function and stepped through it with 12345.111 and still get 12,345,111.  No errors and no decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hack to work around my problem.  It's not pretty, but it works.  I was able to get the numberFormatter to update and show the digits after the decimal but that led to a new issue.  If you typed 12345.00 you would get 12,344 and not see the trailing 0's until you pressed another number. ex 12345.1 -> 12,345.1, 12345.001 -> 12,345.001, but 12345.00 -> 12,345.

I needed it to work dynamically so the user knows how many zeros are being entered.  My hack was to split the final amount into an two arrays.  One pre-formatted and one post-formatted. Then join the two together for the final display number.

I'd still love to find a more efficient solution, if anyone has any ideas.

Here is the updated code.

```
@IBAction func btnTouchDigit(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let digit = sender.currentTitle!
    
    if isUserTyping {
        preFormattedNumber = (display.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ""))!
        
        // set the limit for number of digits user can enter at once
        if display.text!.count >= 16 {
            return
        }  
        else {
            // make sure we aren't adding a second period
            if digit == "." && ((preFormattedNumber.range(of: ".")) != nil) {
                
                print("extra decimal pressed")
                return
            }
            else {
                preFormattedNumber = (preFormattedNumber + digit)
                print("preFormattedNumber before Formatting = \(preFormattedNumber)")
            }
            
            // put code here to format label.text to show thousand seperators
            if ((preFormattedNumber.range(of: ".")) != nil){
                print("just checked for .")
                let numPreFormat = preFormattedNumber
                let numAfterFormat = preFormattedNumber.twoFractionDigits
                let numArray = numPreFormat.components(separatedBy: ".")
                let numArrayFormatted = numAfterFormat.components(separatedBy: ".")
                let afterDecimal = numArray.last
                let beforeDecimal = numArrayFormatted.first
                let finalNumberToDisplay = beforeDecimal! + "." + afterDecimal!
                print("numArray = \(numArray)")
                print("final number to display = \(finalNumberToDisplay)")
                print("numArray = \(numArray)")
                display.text = finalNumberToDisplay
                runningNumber = display.text!
            }
            else {
                display.text = preFormattedNumber.twoFractionDigits
                runningNumber = display.text!
            }
        }
    }    
    // make sure we aren't entering a bunch of zero's
    else { print("else + \(isUserTyping)")
        preFormattedNumber = digit
        display.text = preFormattedNumber
        runningNumber = display.text!
        if digit == "0" {return}
        else if digit == "." { preFormattedNumber = "0.";
        }
        
        display.text = preFormattedNumber
        runningNumber = display.text!
        isUserTyping = true
    }
}
```